# I am getting like these when I am pushing my project in local repository

Tags: git, git-lfs

Uploading LFS objects:   0% (0/13), 0 B | 0 B/s, done.
Unable to find source for object e064c2eecfdc58d552844467da7bd56eca596098322bfd266a7e1312abdd5735 (try running `git lfs fetch --all`)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/sssteja/Flight-Delay-Prediction.git'

I tried git pull commands but not working